# how to make div content draggable

Tags: jquery, html, input, draggable

I met a trouble.

In fact I have many input that must be filled by numbers from 1 to it can be about 100.

What I do actually is to fullfill the input with the keyboard.

But sometime if I do a mistake I do not remember which number was not used and which is not available.

So I decide to write the numbers into divs.

What I would like to do is to make this div draggable.

And when I drag the div into the input it fullfill the input with the content of the div. Actualy I really do not know how to proceed.

I would also if possible to make a div disappear if an input is fullfilled with the div content. Moreover if the input is cleared or the number removed it must set up the div back.

If anyone can bring me some ideas for how to proceed, I'll be glad.

Receive All My utmost Respect.

Kind Regards,

SP.

Comment: I've tried using jquery but the div just move there position the content do not go inside the input

Comment: Please put together an example of what you have tried on jsfiddle

Comment: I've tried something like that http://jsfiddle.net/FqM4A/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here are all you are looking :

- Make elements draggable with jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
- Make elements droppable with jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/